# Typo3, Faceted Search and Workspaces

Tags: typo3

I have typo3 11.5
I use ke_search 4.5.1.

I created a workspace for editing and there are content that are in "editing" status.

Result page of ke_search display contents that are not approved and aro not in live workspace, how can i resolve?

Comment: According to the code at least pages and content elements should not be indexed as the workspace restriction should be in place. Which records are displayed? From ke_search itself or from a custom indexer?

Comment: The record displayed is a tt_content in "editing", it's a "header" content. i use "pages" indexer.